# C++ Access violation calling function from dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am developing an application that will access smart cards using the standard PKCS#11. At this moment the application is working very well both on Ubuntu and OS X. Now I am porting it to Windows, but I am getting an "access violation" exception whenever I call functions from the pkcs#11 library, which is linked at runtime.

Below I tried to reproduce a SSCCE of my code (The place where the exception is happening is identified with a comment).

```
void * libraryHandle = NULL;
CK_RV   rv;
CK_C_GetFunctionList pC_GetFunctionList;
CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR functions;


libraryHandle = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\pteidpkcs11.dll");
if (libraryHandle == NULL)
{
    printf("Library not loaded\n");
    exit(1);
}

pC_GetFunctionList = (CK_C_GetFunctionList) GetProcAddress((HMODULE)libraryHandle, "C_GetFunctionList");

if (pC_GetFunctionList == NULL)
{
    printf("Function not loaded\n");
    FreeLibrary((HMODULE)libraryHandle);
    exit(1);
}

rv = (*pC_GetFunctionList) (&functions);
assert(rv == CKR_OK);
printf("Point A\n");

if(functions == NULL)
{ 
    printf("Functions not loaded\n");
    FreeLibrary((HMODULE)libraryHandle);
    exit(1);        
}

printf("%u - %u\n",functions->version.major, functions->version.minor); // Prints without problems
rv = (*functions->C_Initialize) (NULL_PTR); //THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I AM GETTING THE ACCESS VIOLATION
assert(rv == CKR_OK);

//printf("Point B\n");

FreeLibrary((HMODULE)libraryHandle);
```

When I debug the application the structure "CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR functions" seems to be valid.

Does anyone know what is causing this exception?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Windows XP SP3.

Thanks!

(PS: I have already tried to load the function "C_Initialize" using "GetProcAddress" from the library, and it worked)

--- Edit

CK_FUNCTION_LIST definition

```
struct CK_FUNCTION_LIST {

  CK_VERSION    version;  /* Cryptoki version */

/* Pile all the function pointers into the CK_FUNCTION_LIST. */
/* pkcs11f.h has all the information about the Cryptoki
 * function prototypes. */
#include "pkcs11f.h"

};
```

Full headers in: 
  http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133

Comment: What is the value of `functions->C_Initialize` (i.e. the function address)?  Is it NULL or some other invalid value?

Comment: Please check this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/ix5itwskakd0sku/exec.JPG Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that image, it looks like you either have some sort of disagreement on the layout of your `CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR` structure between the executable and the DLL.  Make sure the executable and DLL are both compiled with the same compiler settings etc.

What is the definition (including any surrounding pragmas/macros) of `CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR`?  Is `sizeof(CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR)` the same if you print out its value from both your executable and from inside the DLL (in, say, `C_GetFunctionList()`)?

Comment: I did not create the dll... Is it possible to get which compiler and definitions were used? I will try to use different headers.

Comment: What do the header files you have look like?

Comment: Somewhere in either your code or a header file you're `#include`ing is a definition of `CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR` (if there weren't, you'd be getting compiler errors about undefined types or not being able to dereference incomplete types or something).  Please post the full, exact definition of that `struct`.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `cryptoki.h` does include the proper `#pragma pack` directives to set the packing.  Are you including `cryptoki.h`?  Or are you directly including the `pkcs11*.h` headers?

Comment: I was including pkcs11.h directly.. Now I included criptoki.h and it worked.. what a noob.. Thanks so much for your help! I am sorry for wasting your time!