# Use PKCS#11 in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, cryptography, token, pkcs#11

I need to connect to a token using the standard PKCS#11.
In my C program, wrote with Visual Studio, I included PKCS#11 headers, downloaded from RSA site and some macros.

```
//define macros
#define CK_PTR *
#define CK_DEFINE_FUNCTION(returnType, name) returnType name
#define CK_DECLARE_FUNCTION(returnType, name) returnType name
#define CK_DECLARE_FUNCTION_POINTER(returnType, name) returnType (* name)
#define CK_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(returnType, name) returnType (* name)
#ifndef NULL_PTR
#define NULL_PTR 0
#endif

#include "pkcs11.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
[..]
   C_Initialize(NULL_PTR);
   [..]
```

When i build it, i get "undefined reference to C_Initialize". The same error for all the pkcs11 function I used. 
In the program directory there are also the other pkcs11 headers. What is the wrong with it?

Comment: Question solved. I add "cryptoki.h" and "pkcs11.h" headers, in addition to "eToken.dll" to communicate to SafeNet eToken. I also follow this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993429/c-access-violation-calling-function-from-dll to call PKCS#11 functions! Thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static linking you need to have a corresponding .lib file. You can have it if you link the application with the SDK of particular hardware device.

The generic approach is to load the DLL given by the end user dynamically. To do this your code needs to use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() Windows API functions to obtain addresses of each function of the library (yes, there are more than 50 functions there if memory serves).

Comment: Do I need OpenCryptoki or OpenSc? On linux I used opencryptoki, and all was fine. I add OpenSc dll to Visual Studio resources, but I don't solve any errors.

Comment: OpenCryptoki should work, I think. OpenSC is a different story.

Comment: Yes, but OpenCryptoki is for Linux, isn't it? Actually i can't find a library!

Comment: @andret8 I believe I saw and installed some open-source PKCS#11 but I can't remember, which one, now. BTW CryptLib supports PKCS#11 as they claim. If no, then it's a couple of hours of work to create dynamic imports as I have written. You've spend more searching for a library.

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking with whatever object file or library that `C_Initialize` function is defined in.

Comment: There is a reference to that function in the headers! See also pkcs11t.h and pkcs11f.h

Comment: @andret8 The headers only *declare* the functions, not *define* them. For that you need to link with the correct library. It's the same if you make a project with two source files, the functions in one source file may be *declared* in a common header file, but you need both source files (or rather, the compiled object files) or you will get the same errors about missing definitions.

Comment: That's ok. Previously i executed my program on Linux, and I got no errors.. maybe I had some libraries that are missing here.